# TypeError: successFunction is not a function - angular.js:13529

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**bookController.js**:

Getting two parameters from url 1) clientid 2) bookId

```
$scope.clientId = $location.search().clientId;
$scope.bookId = $location.search().bookId;
bookService.getSingleBook($scope.clientId, $scope.bookId,$scope.getResponse, $scope.ErrorResponse);
```

**bookService.js**

```
 this.getSingleBook = function (clientId, bookId, successFunction, errorFunction) {
        ajaxService.AjaxGet("http://localhost/samplewebsite/api/Book?clientId=" + clientId + "&bookId=" + bookId, successFunction, errorFunction);
    };
```

**ajaxService.js**

```
 this.AjaxGet = function (route, successFunction, errorFunction) {
        blockUI.start();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: route }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                blockUI.stop();
                successFunction(response);//getting type error
            }).error(function (response) {
                blockUI.stop();
                errorFunction(response);
            });
        }, 1000);

    };
```

**successFunction(response)** is getting data as response but when it returning the response it though an error **TypeError: successFunction is not a function - angular.js:13529**

[image]

Comment: Can you show the declaration of $scope.getResponse ?

Comment: I would also recommend using `$timeout` to ensure that any scope properties you might be updating cause a digest cycle to fire.

Comment: @Nathan Power : $scope.getResponse = function(response){console.log(response);}

Comment: Add declaration of function `$scope.getResponse` in your question.